# When I import the animation into UE, there is an offset

Tags: animation, export, bones, unreal-engine

I am creating a grenade for my project. I want to implement the grenade as a device in UE, with functions such as taking it out and throwing it. I created a bone for my grenade in Blender and associated it with my character's bone (Frag_body bound to TB_handR) (Frag_ring bound to TB_handI) (Frag_body bound to ik_weapon). Then I created animations for it, including arm animations and grenade animations, But when I tried to import the animation into UE, there was a mismatch between the grenade and the hand position. If I don't use ik_ Hand_ If the bone of Gun is bound to it and the position information of the grenade is applied, there will be no displacement of the grenade position.
[image]
[image]
[image]
I think it's the rotation of my grenade bone in world coordinates, or maybe not. Because I just got to know Blender. All of my animations are bound and baked according to the prescribed steps.

I have tried to remake bones, remake animations, and rebind bones, but there are still the above issues. May I ask what is the solution so that I can use IK_ Hand_ After binding the grenade, the bone Gun does not show any misalignment